# why there is need float function

Tags: c, graphics

**//DDA Function for line generation**
  here, for calculating increment in x and y, float is used, what is need to use float there,
if not use what will affect

```
void DDA(int X0, int Y0, int X1, int Y1) 
{ 
    // calculate dx & dy 
    int dx = X1 - X0; 
    int dy = Y1 - Y0; 

    // calculate steps required for generating pixels 
    int steps = abs(dx) > abs(dy) ? abs(dx) : abs(dy); 

    // calculate increment in x & y for each steps 
    float Xinc = dx / (float) steps; 
    float Yinc = dy / (float) steps; 

    // Put pixel for each step 
    float X = X0; 
    float Y = Y0; 
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i <= steps; i++) 
    { 
        putpixel (X,Y,RED);  // put pixel at (X,Y) 
        X += Xinc;           // increment in x at each step 
        Y += Yinc;           // increment in y at each step 
        delay(100);          // for visualization of line- 
                             // generation step by step 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Try yourself - remove the floats and test it.

Comment: yes i tried, the output was one dot only instead of line

Comment: You can draw lines using just integer arithmetic, but you have to concentrate hard on the remainders.  Each pixel wants to be within half a pixel of its "true" position.  With float you can naturally track the "true" position.  To do that with integers you keep two parts, the whole number and a fraction: each step adds `delta / steps` to the whole number and `delta % steps` to the fraction, and if the fraction then exceeds or equals `steps / 2`, you need to adjust the whole number and the fraction (up and down, respectively).

Comment: once again i runes the program by removing float and output was horizontal straight line, there was no increment in y direction, what was actually happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the variables *dx*, *dy* and *steps* are integer, so if you don't cast (float) the result of `dx/steps` or `dy/steps` is always integer. You can also use `1.0 * dx/steps` instead of using `(float) steps`

You can test by the code below (or on the online platform [link](https://ideone.com/ePss67)):

```
int main() {
   int a = 3;
   int b = 10;
   float c;
   c = (float) b/ a;
   printf("%f\n", c);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: can i use (float) dx/steps insted of dx/(float) steps

Comment: yes, but why don't you test it. Try it by yourself and see what happen, then you can learn from your test

Answer (score 0):

(float) will convert the expression type to float.

If float is not used at:

```
float Xinc = dx / (float) steps;  // float Xinc = dx / steps;
```

Then the result of (dx / steps) will be truncated to int (5 / 2 will be 2).